# How to merge a Line Item row to the above Row based on condition

Tags: c#

I have a Table with the below column names.

> 1) HSN Code
>   2) Item Code
>   3) Unit Cost
>   4) Total

If the "HSN Code" field value is empty in any row I want to merge the remaining fields data to the Above row. How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question. It always helps if you could show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: please be more precise. "Table" what kind of ? DataBase? Excel? DataTable? If It is a database table, what is it oracle? SQL? something else? what do you use to access it? ADO.NET? Linq2SQL? Entity Framework? something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int numberColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                if(row["HSN Code"] == string.Empty)
                {
                    row["HSN Code"] = string.Join(",", row.ItemArray.Skip(1).Select(x => x.ToString()));
                    for (int i = 1; i < numberColumns; i++)
                    {
                        row[i] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
```